# iOS Header StackView with correct alignment?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a `UIView` which will be a header. **Note** I am only focused on implementing the header (as shown below) in this question.

Here is how it is supposed to be look like (the HEADER is in yellow)

[image]

Basically, the header `UIView` should have a `UIBUTTON` all the way to the left and a `UILabel` exactly in the middle, nothing on the right

The problem I am having is how I will make the `UIView` for this.

My idea was have a main horizontal `UIStackView`, but if I put a `UILabel` and `UIButton` into it, how can I (in code) align it in the way I've described? I am unable to use the UI Builder for this, but have to lay it out in Objective C code.

`@interface HeaderView : UIView`

```
@implementation HeaderView {
   UIStackView mainHorizontalStackView; 
   UIButton leftButton;
   UILabel middleLabel; 
}

-(instanceType) initializer(){
   mainHorizontalStackView = ... //alloc
   leftButton = ...
   middleLabel = ...

  // how do I set up the constraints to make it fit the desired setup?

}
```

Comment: Look's like navigation bar for me 

Comment: If you want to use StackView, then you can try adding the button, label and an empty view to the StackView. You should also add constraint to set the width of these 3 views to be equal.

Comment: Without using StackView, You can align the middleLabel by setting `middleLabel.center = CGPointMake(headerView.frame.size.width  / 2, headerView.frame.size.height / 2);`. Similary you can left align the leftButton by calculating its frame based on the header view frame.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic example of creating your custom view:

**HeaderView.h**

```
//
//  HeaderView.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/7/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface HeaderView : UIView
@end
```

**HeadView.m**

```
//
//  HeaderView.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/7/20.
//

#import "HeaderView.h"

@interface HeaderView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *leftButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *centeredLabel;

@end

@implementation HeaderView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        // default background color
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.95 blue:0.8 alpha:1.0];
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor brownColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;

        _leftButton = [UIButton new];
        [_leftButton setTitle:@"BUTTON" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_leftButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _leftButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        _centeredLabel = [UILabel new];
        _centeredLabel.text = @"LABEL";
        _centeredLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self addSubview:_leftButton];
        [self addSubview:_centeredLabel];

        // adjust constant values if "padding" from edges desired

        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

            // constrain button to left, top, bottom
            [_leftButton.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor constant:4.0],
            [_leftButton.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor constant:8.0],
            [_leftButton.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor constant:-8.0],

            // constrain label centered horizontally in view, centered vertically to button
            [_centeredLabel.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor],
            [_centeredLabel.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_leftButton.centerYAnchor],

        ]];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**TestViewController.h**

```
//
//  TestViewController.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/7/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

**TestViewController.m**

```
//
//  TestViewController.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/7/20.
//

#import "TestViewController.h"

#import "HeaderView.h"

@interface TestViewController ()
@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    HeaderView *v = [HeaderView new];
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:v];

    // respect safe area
    UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

        // constrain header view top / leading / trailing to self.view (safe area)
        // adjust constant values if "padding" from edges desired
        [v.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:0.0],
        [v.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:8.0],
        [v.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-8.0],

    ]];

}

@end
```

Result:

[image]